# Reference a dict as a class attribute

Tags: python, class, dictionary, reference, attributes

How to set a reference to a dictionary to be part of a classes attributes, even after its values are updated?

```
live = {'APPL': {'bid': 41, 'ask': 43}}
extras = {'name': 'apple', 'country': 'us', 'currency': 'usd'}

class myClass:
 def __init__(self, live_data, extra_data):
  self.__dict__ = live_data
  self.__dict__.update(extra_data)

 def update(self, extra_data):
  self.__dict__.update(extra_data)


symbol = myClass(live['APPL'], extras)
```

If the variable 'live' is updated, all works out.
If the variable 'extras' is updated, the instance attribute loses it's reference.

**Updating dict data...**

```
live['APPL']['bid'] = 40
live['APPL'].update({'ask': 44})
extras['country'] = 'uk'
extras.update({'currency': 'gbp'})
```

**Instance 'symbol' doesn't properly update**

```
In: symbol.bid
Out: 40
In: symbol.ask
Out: 44
In: symbol.country
Out: 'us'
In: symbol.currency
Out: 'usd'
```

How to keep the attribute reference to the dictionaries that keep updating its values as soon as new data arrives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of modifying `self.__dict__`, define a `__getattr__()` method:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, live_data, extra_data):
        self._live = live_data
        self._extra = extra_data

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._extra:
            return self._extra[name]
        elif name in self._live:
            return self._live[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("No attribute: {}".format(name)
```

Comment: It has worked flawlessly, but using this method on every call is substantially slower than the previous work around.  `1.24 µs per loop vs 164 ns per loop` Because this code runs many times per second, any ideas or suggestions that allow class attributes to maintain reference to dict items are welcome.